# How to get the path of a ".lnk" file using tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames() in python 3.10? Or any other ways?

Tags: python, tkinter

My work needs me to collect some file names and their generating time.

I am using the `fileName = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames()` to realize the function, that the program pops up a window to ask for selecting files, then I can get the files' pathes and then use `fileGeneratedTime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(fileName))` to get the files' generating time.

But now here comes the problem. When I want to get the path of a `.lnk` file, however, it returns the path of the file which the `.lnk` file is pointing to. It is OK to run the program on the origin computer that has the .lnk files, but when I copy the .lnk files to other computers, the program says `FileNotFoundError`.

So, is there any parameters that can make the `fileName = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilenames()` returns the .lnk file itself's path (not the path of the file which the .lnk file points to)? Or is there any other ways to realize the same function?

Thanks for your answering!

Comment: *but when I copy the .lnk files to other computers, the program says "FileNotFoundError".* Why do you expect to find the file on a different computer? Ps: you could use `os.readlink`